# use regular expression in laravel routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have some legacy routes and I should redirect all of them to page 404. All of them have `admin` and `user` at the beginning. What are best practices to do this?

e.g. is there anyway to use regular expresion?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
Route::get('{legacy}', function($legacy){
    //
})->where('legacy', 'user.*|admin.*');
```

Answer (score 1):

So Laravel can be a bit vague in terms of documentation about catch-all routes, you can use the following (untested) to catch any optional route below a given route and redirect back to a 404 page.

```
// Redirect all /admin routes
Route::get('admin/{any?}', function ($any = null) {
    return redirect('404');
})->where('any', '.*');

// Redirect all /user routes
Route::get('user/{any?}', function ($any = null) {
    return redirect('404');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Personally I'd probably set up a rewrite to do this via a 301 permanent redirect before it even hits Laravel, but this should help you out in the meantime.